# What's the best way to create and manage palettes on Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, palette, linux

I'd like to find a solution to create and manage (edit, save, export) palettes on a Linux laptop.

Ideally I'd like to have functionalities similar to webapps like [Coolors](https://coolors.co/), [Colormind](http://colormind.io/), [Paletton](http://paletton.com/), or to Android apps like the awesome [Color Harmony](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.powsty.colorharmony).

In case you wonder, I'd like to manage them locally without having to rely on websites (I don't want to create new accounts just for this) or to Apps on my smartphone, having a Desktop solution would be the perfect way to integrate this kind of task in my workflow.

Comment: Why not make your own?

Comment: A quick web search reveals two: [gpick](http://www.gpick.org/) and [agave](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Agave)

Comment: Linux is a good concept, we use it a lot. Are you indirectly saying that you want free tools, like you do not want to spend any money? OpenSource only? Or would you consider quality commercial tools that run on Linux? Hobby tools hardly have need for color management at a several-palettes-level, that is why I am asking.

Comment: @BillyKerr You are the man! Please write an answer, even just that. So that I can upvote it. I liked what you linked. Do not need it now, but I am "abusing" this exchange for my personal documentation, by way of favoriting.

Comment: There is never one "best way". You get better answers, if you rephrase "what are good ways" and then give your personal context and examples of your workflow.

Comment: @MartinZaske - I'm sorry but I don't have enough information on these apps to create a detailed answer, also I've only dabbled in Linux and I'm no expert. I don't think the admins would appreciate such a short answer without details. If you know more, I'd invite you to answer. Feel free to elaborate on my suggestions, or to add them to your existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a start here and look what is available:

https://www.freiefarbe.de/en/

Also consider that mostly, a palette is "just a file". So your "management" could possibly be done in your preferred file-explorer: Well named folders, good file names or versioning as needed.

You have not named your preferred tools for using such palettes and how massively you want to edit them. Most graphics tools in Linux (like Inkscape and Scribus or GIMP) allow you to import or edit palettes. And then export of course.

If you want to make or show/print entire palettes from scratch, you might find yourself writing or finding-and-tweaking scripts, like some Scribus users are doing (check out the Scribus mailing list for examples).